# Error with loop that saves values in an array: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I want to save given values (input) in an array. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I'm not able to save the last value, because I get the following error:

> ---> 18         zax[k].append(abs)
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Do you know what went wrong?

Here's my code:

```
    ax = np.array([])
    k = 0
    l = 0

    mehrfach = int(input('Please write how often you measured your samples.\n
Please write an integer. For example: Duplicates: 2; Triplicates: 3; etc.'))
    werte = int(input('Please write how much samples you have.\n
Please write an integer. For example: Two different samples: 2; Three different samples: 3, etc.'))
    zax=[[] for k in range(mehrfach)]
    #while k < (werte):
    for k in range(werte):
    #for k in range(werte): #samples
        #while l < (mehrfach): #duplicates
        for l in range (mehrfach):
            abs = float(input('Please write down your measured absoprtion (float).'))
            zax[k].append(abs)
            l = l+1
        k = k+1
    print('Measured absorptions:',zax)
```

Cheers

Comment: why do you do k = k+1? That will increase k by 2 for one iteration.

Comment: `zax[k].append(abs)` is based on `k in range(werte)` but you create your list `zax` with `k in range(mehrfach)`

Comment: Also you don't need to initialize k and l. They are zero by default.

Comment: Thank you @BenoîtZu. You solved the problem I didn't see. And thank you Ashbourne for giving me advices.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a validation check to make sure `werte` is not greater than `mehrfach`.  If `werte` is greater than `mehrfach` you will get an `IndexError` in the inner loop trying to set `zax[k]`.

The reason being you are setting `zax` to be a list with n lists where n is equal to `mehrfach`.  In your loop you are trying to set a list item with `zax[k]` where k is defined from `werte`.  If `werte` > `mehrfach` you will be trying to set of value `zax[k]` in your inner loop that does not exist and the `IndexError` is being thrown.